# using multiple c-ares channels in a select() loop

Tags: c++, c, c-ares

I'm new to the c-ares library and I want to extend the example below such that I can simultaneously wait for multiple queries to complete. Here is a working example:

```
void processChannelBlocking(Channel &c) {
    int nfds, count;
    fd_set readers, writers;
    struct timeval tv;
    while (c.isRunning()) {
        FD_ZERO(&readers);
        FD_ZERO(&writers);
        tv.tv_sec  = std::numeric_limits<typeof(tv.tv_sec)>::max();
        tv.tv_usec = std::numeric_limits<typeof(tv.tv_usec)>::max();
        nfds = c.updateFDs(&readers, &writers);
        if (nfds == 0)   break;
        c.updateTimeout(&tv);
        count = select(nfds, &readers, &writers, NULL, &tv);
        c.process(&readers, &writers);
        std::cout<<"loop"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

- `updateFDs()` gets the FDs for a channel
- `updateTimeout()` lowers the timeout to what a channel requires
- `process()` is `ares_process()`

I can easily setup `select()` to wait for multiple channels, but when `select()` returns, how can I tell which channel to call `ares_process` on?

Comment: The manual page for `select()` clearly explains how to check which file descriptor is ready for reading or writing. Which part of the `select()` manual page you don't understand?

Comment: This isn't a select() question. The question is: which channel do I process after the select() returns some subset of FDs? It's not easy to associate FDs to channels the way c-ares is setup. I feel like I'm missing something with c-ares.

Comment: after select you can again call updateFDs for specific channel and if the flag is set in both sets - returned by the channels updateFDs and returned by select - then this channel has to process this FD

Comment: @Artemy What if there are no FDs in the sets because a timeout occurred for one of the channels?

Comment: A worthy and misunderstood question. I'm looking into it also. One approach when establishing the fds would be to use ares_fds() on an empty fd_set for each channel in turn, so discovering the fds used by each channel and combining these into an overall set. Thus it would be possible to know on the return of select which channel has any activity by testing against each individual channel's fdset. Or simpler, given that ares_process() is passed the fd_set, maybe calling ares_process() when there's no fd activity is fine, so blindly calling for all channels regardless of any activity would work.